# Jquery animation loop glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I trying to make this animation loop:

```
var speed = 0.08;
function animate_div(object){
    var duration = (object.position().left + object.width()) / speed;
    object.animate(
        {left: -object.width()},
        duration,
        'linear',
        function(){
            object.css('left', parseInt($('#container').width())+'px');
            animate_div(object);
        }
    );
}
$('#container div').each(function(){
    animate_div($(this));
});
```

A running example in this jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/toutr2002/5m79bow5/)

There's a glitch occur randomly on the animation (the animation stop for short time). Is there a way to make this animation smoother?

Best regards,

Comment: If possible you can use css3

Comment: ya, like demonofthemist said, using css3 transforms/transitions would likely be smoother if you dont have to support shitty browsers.